# Hide a Form From Task Manager Application Tab in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, taskmanager

I try to make an application with three Forms, and I didn't want the two other Forms is shown in the taskbar and in Task Manager Application tab. I set their `ShowInTaskbar` to `False` and it works.

But when I open my Task Manager both three of their name are listed at the Application Tab. So how can I make them not show in Task Manager?

And I still want it to be appear in process tab, but not in application tab. Because if I have 3 form, in application tab will show Form1, Form2, Form3 name.

Comment: Why would you not want to show them in the Task Manager? The purpose for them there is so users can see what's running and can close an unresponsive program, see what's using memory etc. Also you don't hide the Form from there, you hide the executable.

Comment: @Zaggler : I think he wants to hide the window from being shown in the "Applications" tab, but to still be visible under "Processes". In Windows 10 these have been combined into one tab, but in Windows 7 and earlier they're two different tabs.

Comment: I *think* this changed in Win10, ShowInTaskbar=false used to be enough.  You'll have to convince Task Manager that it is a "helper" window.  That requires displaying it with the Show(owner) overload so it is an owned window.  Or setting its FormBorderStyle property to SizeableToolWindow.

Comment: I still want it to be appear in process tab, but not in application tab. Because if I have 3 form, in application tab will show Form1, Form2, Form3 name.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your project

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H80
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Could help you?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following (assuming you use visual studio ):

1. Open the Soluion / project
2. Open the properties of your program / project
3. Go to the "Application Tab"
4. Change the Application Type to Windows service

Now your program should show up as background proccess in the taskmanager, not as Application.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. One still has to create the service and its `OnStart` and `OnStop` method. -- Also, since he uses multiple forms one would assume that he is showing some kind of user interface, which cannot be done in a simple manner through a service. AND EVEN IF he does show forms from the service they'd still be shown in the `Applications` tab in the task manager, unless the initial problem is fixed.

Comment: He even specifically asks to hide _two out of three_ forms, not the entire app.